# Dependency inject ancestor component of same type?

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular's dependency injection allows you to inject any ancestor component, like so:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(_parent: AppComponent) {}
}
```

But In my case, I want to inject an ancestor component that is another instance of the same component class, like this:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(_parent: MyComponent) {}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

This produces a cyclical dependency error, presumably because it refers to the very same instance.

In my case, I cannot inject the other component via `@Input()` since it's not going to be a direct parent, but a fully-dynamic/unknown grandfather/great-grandfather component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `@SkipSelf()`decorator.

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  constructor(@SkipSelf() @Optional() private parent: HelloComponent) {
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egjne9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)